# Transfer everything from Joomla VirtueMart 2 to VirtueMart 2

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, migration, virtuemart

I am new to Joomla VirtueMart. I would like to transfer everything (including products, images, categories, etc) from my Joomla VirtueMart2 site to another website that is using VirtueMart2 as well. What is the easiest and fastest way to process? Thank you for your responses.

//P.S. I know there are some commercial extensions that I might be able to use, however, most of them are to migrate VM1 to VM2, which is not quite what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. All you have to do is take a backup/export all the database tables for VirtueMart from your old Joomla site's database, then upload/import them to the database for your new Joomla site. You can access the database using PHPMyAdmin

Comment: You will also need to copy across the images and thumbnails from the relative folders. You could also use CSV Improved (there's a free version) to do this without having to manipulate the database directly: http://www.csvimproved.com/